# 08 Mazda CX-9: Is this a transmission leak?

Tags: mazda, oil-leak

After doing my first oil change etc, I noticed whist under the car some isolated gunk/oil/? by what looks like transmission pan:

[image]
As well as something on the left (do not know what this is):

[image]
I am not sure if these gunk blotches are actively leaking but they are sticky. Does this look like an active leak? What are the parts of the engine being affected by the gunk?

I would have said that the pan had a leaking gasket but I am not sure the color of the gunk is correct, and that would not explain the splodge on the other side of the middle peice.

Any recommendations on how to root cause this? or is it even a concern at all?

Comment: When I was a mechanic in the Army, we had three levels of leaks: Class I, II, & III. The definitions of these were: C1=film present; C2=Drip forming; C3=See it drip. What you have here is *barely* a C1 leak. Depending on the mileage on your Mazda, this to me would not be much to worry about. I cannot tell where the leak is coming from, so am leaving this as a comment.

Comment: That's an interesting way of categorizing, ill remember that, cheers. That bit between the two leaky spots is not the transfer case is it?

Comment: I am not really sure. I'm not getting a sense of where we really are from the pictures.

Comment: It's tough to ignore since many transmissions don't have dipsticks any more. With any leak present, you are never quite sure what the fluid level is. Back in the days of dipsticks in transmissions, maybe you put this off for a while.

Comment: I checked this morning, mine does have a dip stick thankfully and when I pulled it, it was way over full. Vehicle was cold parked all night so perhaps that's normal, something to look at. But it appears I do not have tranny fluid loss. I think I need to get under there again. Is it okay to clean all these areas with break cleaner fluid? Don't want to hurt gaskets.

Comment: I think in general you want to check tranny fluid dip stick with the engine running. could be wrong.